# How to find/replace string field in dataframe?

Tags: python, string, dataframe, replace

I want to replace string that ends in `".F"` with `".DE"`

I tried :

```py
data["field"] = data.field.str.replace(".F",".DE")
```

but strangely it replaces  `"BFb.N"` into `".DEb.N"`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

[Pandas String Replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html)

You probably think `".F"` means to look for .F and replace it, but that's not what's happening.  It's not treating `".F"` as a string, it's treating it as a regular expression, which is an entirely different thing.  In a regular expression `".F"` means any character plus F, which is why you are seeing this behavior.  Staying w/the regular expression you can add a `\` to your `.` to make it a literal period, such as `"\.F"` and it should solve your problem.

Alternatively you can tell pandas not to treat it as a regular expression and it should also solve your problem

```
data.field.str.replace(".F",".DE", regex=False)
```

Comment: @Nite feel free to accept this as the correct answer so others can find it!